# Create function to returned the set of rows bases on the input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I need to create a function where the course category (name) will be used as parameter, and it will return a set of trainings related to it and the number of attendees.

and I don't know where to start. I've done something like these, for the beginning:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_course_cat (@course_cat_name VARCHAR)  
RETURNS table
AS RETURN 
( SELECT
    CASE WHEN @course_cat_name = 'Business' THEN 
    (SELECT course_name, cc.course_category_id
        FROM dbo.course_category CC
        join dbo.course c on c.course_category_id = CC.course_category_id
        WHERE c.course_category_id = 2)
    END
FROM dbo.course_category CC
join dbo.course c on c.course_category_id = CC.course_category_id);
GO
```

However, I receive an error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure f_course_cat, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 261]
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I have 3 tables:

```sql
SELECT * FROM course_category
```

```
course_category_id  course_category_name
2                    Business
1                    Development
3                    Finance & Accounting
4                    IT & Software
6                    Marketing
5                    Personal development
```

```
SELECT * FROM course
```

```
course_id   course_name                               course_category_id    
1            Agile Kanban: Kanban for Software Development Teams    4   
2            Successful Negotiation: Master Your Negotiating Skill  5   
3            Customer Service: Soft Skills Fundamentals             5   
4            Git & GitHub - The Practical Guide                     1   
5            React - The Complete Guide                             1   
6            Complete C# Masterclass                                1   
7            Learn Parallel Programming with C# and .NET            1   
8            OAuth 2.0 in Spring Boot Applications                  1   
9            Selenium WebDriver with Docker, Jenkins & AWS          1   
10           Microsoft Power BI - A Complete Introduction           2   
11           Facebook Ads B2B: Advertising+ Facebook Ads for B2B    6   
12           Business Fundamentals: Marketing Strategy              6   
13           Finance for Non Finance Executives                     3   
14           The Complete Introduction To Accounting and Finance    3   
15           Finance 101: Financial Management & DCF Fundamental    3   
16           Practical Finance                                      3
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM training_history
```

```
employee_id course_id   start_date  end_date    training_status_id
1               13      2020-11-17  NULL         2
2               5       2021-06-02  2021-09-03   3
4               7       2020-12-08  2021-06-25   3
3               9       2021-09-08  NULL         1
1               13      2020-11-17  NULL         2
2               5       2021-06-02  2021-09-03   3
4               7       2020-12-08  2021-06-25   3
3               9       2021-09-08  NULL         1
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem; what about the error don't you understand here, and we can *try* to elaborate, but it is quite specific. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to input as a parameter for example 'Development' and it will show all the course names with category type 'Development'

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_course_cat (@course_cat_name VARCHAR(200)) 
RETURNS table AS 
return
        SELECT course_name, cc.course_category_id
        FROM dbo.course_category CC
        join dbo.course c on c.course_category_id = CC.course_category_id
        WHERE CC.Name = @course_cat_name
```

Comment: I tried this,
`CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_course_cat (@course_cat_name VARCHAR)` 
`RETURNS table`
`AS RETURN`
  `SELECT course_name, cc.course_category_id`
    `FROM dbo.course_category CC`
    `join dbo.course c on c.course_category_id = CC.course_category_id`
    `WHERE CC.course_category_name = @course_cat_name`
`GO`

 and it gives me an empty array with course_name and course_category_id when I do for example: 
`SELECT *`
`FROM dbo.f_course_cat('Business')`

Comment: It will, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft . `'Business'` doesn't fit in a `varchar(1)`, and there are no rows with the value `'B'` in the column `course_category_name`.

Comment: @Larnu spotted the error.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu and David I thought if declare just VARCHAR it will take maximum length of 255, but it seems it's not the case, haha, will take it into the consideration for the future! Thank you guys, you're awesome!

Comment: 255 is *far* from the maximum length of a `varchar`, @Vladimir . A `varchar(MAX)` can hold up to ~2 **billion** characters (and a non-`MAX` up to 8,000).